# Creating safe AA wallet from python

Tags: safe-core

I am using a django service as a backend and was wondering if there is a way to create and manage AA safe wallets from python?

I found this library from googling https://gnosis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html but dont see any references to it in the safe docs (https://docs.safe.global/) and was nervous about using it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the safe-eth-py library and the associated docs here: https://safe-eth-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html

The docs are linked from the official GitHub repository for the project here: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-eth-py

We are currently working on consolidating all these docs under docs.safe.global and this is valuable feedback. Hope it helps!